# How do I find the previous div to ui item jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am implementing the sortable functionality to my page. In order to do that I need to find the previous element's `id`.
I want to do something like `ui.item.prev('div').attr('id')`. Please tell me how do I do that?

Comment: With previous element do you mean the parent of your selected elemet?

Comment: I'm not sure your syntax is correct. `.prev()` is a jQuery method, so `ui.item` needs to be a jQuery object (collection).

Answer (score 0):

[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) are your friends:

```
var parent_id = $('ul').closest('div').attr('id');
// i-am-a-div
```

For example:

```
<div id="i-am-a-div">
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```